# How can I pass-through parameters in a powershell function?

Tags: function, powershell, function-parameter

I have a function that looks something like this:

```
function global:Test-Multi {
    Param([string]$Suite)
    & perl -S "$Suite\runall.pl" -procs:$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
}
```

I would like to allow the user to specify more parameters to Test-Multi and pass them directly to the underlying legacy perl script.

Does powershell provide a mechanism to allow additional variadic behavior for this purpose?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After seeing your comment, option 3 sounds like exactly what you want.

---

You have a few options:

1. Use `$args` (credit to [hjpotter92's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33702000/3905079))
2. Explicitly define your additional parameters, then parse them all in your function to add them to your perl call.
3. Use a single parameter with the [`ValueFromRemainingArguments` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#valuefromremainingarguments-argument), e.g.

   ```
    function global:Test-Multi {
        Param(
            [string]$Suite,
            [parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
            [string[]]$Passthrough
            )
        & perl -S "$Suite\runall.pl" -procs:$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS @Passthrough
    }
   ```

Comment: I don't think your "ValueFromRemainingArguments" link goes to the right place....

Comment: @BillyONeal thank you, updated. It's a long-ish document, so `CTRL+F` for `ValueFromRemainingArguments` is recommended.

Comment: @BillyONeal nice, I really should have added an example

Answer (score 14):

`$args` is not going to pass through arguments correctly.  if you want the arguments to remain as separate arguments, you should use `@args` instead.

Comment: Huge thanks! It was exactly what I needed. Using `$` formats your arguments as a single string. `@` is the way to go for a proper pass.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about what you wish to achieve, but the arguments passed to a function are accessible in the `$args` variable available inside the function.

Comment: But $args would contain '-Suite' and its setting as well. I only want to forward arguments my function is not handling.

Comment: @BillyONeal You can filter the `$args` array and remove `-Suite` parameter.

Comment: sure, I can think of ways to do it, but if PS already had a formal way to declare this I wanted to use that.

Comment: To pass the received args to another function, one must use @args and not $args